# Почему нельзя применить тему для Activity

Tags: java, android

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme with this activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваша Активити является потомком AppCompatActivity (MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity) и оно должно использовать тему из пространства имен Theme.AppCompat.

Вам подойдет:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```